# Confirmation emails

Tags: email

Recently Gmail added shortcuts at the bottom of incoming emails for people to click and respond.

It is causing issues for us as the customer sees boxes that say yes proceed with the order, or no I changed my mind, and so forth after they have placed the order.

We suspect it is being driven by the keywords in the email that we could edit to say your order receipt instead of saying thank you for your order.

Any suggestions on how we can edit or change this it is causing confusion and the assumption that if they don't click proceed then they are not authorizing the order after it is placed.